# How to generate a google drive link with token for a session per user?

Tags: google-drive-api

I frequently share content around on google drive from a site - problem - users bookmark the drive link and share it around which beats the point and hardwork put into the webpage itself.

Question:

How do I create a link that works such that when a user goes through it the link is available for that user only - or for x amount of time (lets says 4 days)

So that even if its bookmarked it wont work, and the user needs to visit the page back again to get a link.

Can't seem to find any tutorials that can get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant Creating a link on google drive makes it available to anyone who has the link.

It is possible to share it with just one person in the web view of Google drive.  I have not been able to get this to work with the api though [sharing](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

The closest i have come is sharing the file directly to a user which isnt the same thing as giving them a temp link [manage sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing)